# Force to use specific number of cores

Tags: multi-core, scaling

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 on laptop that has Intel i5 (4 logical cores).
Question: Can I force Ubuntu to use only one or two cores?

Explanation:
I want to test how my application performance scales when machine has more cores available.
I know that it is easier to do it on virtual machine (and assign specific number of cores) but on virtual machine I am afraid, that amount of RAM memory will be not sufficient. Application consumes up to 3GB of RAM and my laptop has only 4GB of RAM.

Comment: But this answer requires recompiling kernel after config change. Is there any other (easier) way?

Comment: Why I nominate this for reopening: The duplicate question is asking for how to increase the number of supported cores, which can be only solved by recompiling the kernel. This question is asking for a solution on how to temporarily "disable" some cores. They are not the same question. For the question marked as duplicate the only solution is the recompilation, for this question there might be other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you boot with the `isolcpus=2,3` option it will limit you to 2 cores, `isolcpus=1,2,3` will limit to 1 core.